# How to add a MySQL Trigger via PHP Form (Prestashop 1.5.4 : installation module)

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, prestashop-1.5

i have to make a module who change the short description block dynamically. But this block didn't exist in Prestashop 1.5.4 if the short description is null, so i thought to make a trigger to fill it if it's empty.

Here is my install function :

```
public function install()
{
  if 
  (
    !parent::install() 
    OR !$this->registerHook('displayProductStatus') 
    OR !$this->registerHook('displayOverrideTemplate')
  ) {
      return FALSE;
    }


    $sql = array();
    include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/init/install_sql.php');
    foreach ($sql as $s) 
    {
        if (!Db::getInstance()->Execute($s)) 
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

And here is my install_sql.php

```
<?php

$sql = array();

$sql[] = "DELIMITER $$

            CREATE TRIGGER add_short_description
            BEFORE INSERT ON ps_product_lang
            for each row begin 
            if (NEW.description_short is NULL OR NEW.description_short = '' ) THEN
            SET NEW.description_short = '.';
            END IF;
            END$$

            DELIMITER ;";
```

This trigger function pretty well if i add this directly into PHPMyAdmin, but the install fail when i pass by the module installation.
I think it's the delimiter's fault but... I don't know how to avoid this.

What i have to modify?

(and sorry for my poor english, i hope it is at least comprehensible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `DELIMITER` is a mysql client tool command only and not part of SQL. Therefore you shouldn't include it.

2) Now you can turn your trigger in "one-liner"

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER add_short_description
BEFORE INSERT ON ps_product_lang
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.description_short = COALESCE(NULLIF(NEW.description_short, ''), '.')
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be56a/1)** demo

3) I have no enough knowledge about Prestashop but adding a trigger as a part of module maybe a **very bad** idea because it may easily introduce side effects especially if `ps_product_lang` is part of a common schema. 
I personally would be **very** pissed off if some third-party module would start creating triggers in my database.

Comment: It's worked :) thank you !

I don't know any other "light" way to do that. I thought about a method who changes the change description when i have to do, but this will execute so much update on this table.
Furthermore, the short description couldn't be translated (Prestashop works with Smarty) :/

Anyway, thank you !